# Showing direction to a location predefined by the user in Google Maps

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app where the user first has to define his home location and then whenever he/she presses a button, I want the app to show directions to their home . How to proceed? I actually dont know well about the Google Maps API . I am using Eclipse for building this app.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to read up on the [google directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) 
The [google maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Some follow up questions:
Do you want your application to display the directions or are you going to let google maps APK handle this?
Personally this is the best option and is very simple to code, the code would look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=" +Lat+","+Long));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

You pass it the Lat and Long of their "home" and let google maps navigation handle this for you.